# Hide a view when a button inside of it is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parent-child, uicontainerview

I have a viewController, inside of it I added a "container view" which I want to hide or change its size when a button (that is inside of the container view) is clicked, how can I do that?
[image]

Comment: "Can I access properties declared in the .h file of the parentVC from a containerVC?" Certainly. What's the problem? (Aside from the fact that parent _means_ container; perhaps everywhere you say "container" you mean "child"?)

Comment: " considering containerVC is an IBOutlet declared in the in the parentVC?" No no no no. Parent and child already have access to one another. Don't add more relationships to the mix.

Comment: @matt edited the question.

Comment: and I answered it

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are asking about the relationship between a parent view controller and a child view controller?

- The child is the parent's `childViewControllers[0]` (or possibly some other index, if the parent has multiple children.
- The parent is the child's `parentViewController`.

Thus, the two have access to one another. If a property in the other view controller is public, just cast the other view controller to its correct class and use that property.